# Filter object by value

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Let's say I have:

```
let object1 = [{id: 15, name: name1}, {id: 0, name: name2}, {id: 98, name: name3}];
let object2 = [{id: 2, action: action}, {id: 88, action: action}, {id: 0, action: action}];
```

ID numbers don't match on purpose.
How could I get name values from object1 whose ID's don't appear in object2?

Edit: I've tried to

```
let results;
for (let i = 0; i < object1.length; i++) {
         results = object2.filter(element => { return element.id != object1[i].id } );
    }
```

Also tried to get it working with .map(), but with no luck.

Comment: Your question sounds actually like you haven't try anything and expect a free code service. This is going to be really badly welcomed. If you've tried anything, please show us your attempts

Comment: Oh sorry about that. Let me go through something that I've tried so far! Editing the original post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `filter()` on one of the arrays and `find()` to filter out the objects from that array with ids that don't occur in the other array.

```js
let oArr1 = [{id: 15, name: "name1"}, {id: 0, name: "name2"}, {id: 98, name: "name3"}];
let oArr2 = [{id: 2, action: "action"}, {id: 88, action: "action"}, {id: 0, action: "action"}];

const result = oArr1.filter(x => !oArr2.find(y => y.id === x.id));

console.log(result);
```